# How Parse KNX/IP on Wireshark

Tags: pcap, wireshark-dissector, knx

I have recently purchased a drone and I downloaded the app that is used to control it. I was able to generate packet capture pcap file from the traffic between the drone and the app and saw on wireshark that it's using KNXIP protocol but don't know how to parse it. I looked up KNX briefly online but couldn't find any dissector for wireshark. Is there any packet definition that I can look at to understand KNX protocol. Or is there any parser that can help me parse the captured packet?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFg1J.png)

Comment: The KNX/IP dissector is part of the current Wireshark release. Are you sure the protocol is KNX/IP? This building automation protocol seems to be a rather odd choice for drone control.

Comment: sorry for late response. Yes, it is. Attaching a screenshot to original post.

Comment: The observation that Wireshark *tries* to display it as KNXnet/IP does not mean that it actually *is* this protocol. In fact, as you can see, the KNXnet/IP dissector fails to interpret the message.

Comment: If it's on/using a custom port, you might have to set-up/apply the dissector for that non-standard/different(/custom) port #.